# Remove entire linked list C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

My program uses a linked list to enter in numbers in order.

```
My input: 2 4 23 34 534 543
```

When I go to delete the list I get this:

```
137429056 137428992 137429040 137429024 137429008 0
```

Why is that?

```
void deleteList(node* head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("List is empty\n");

    else
        deleteList(head->next);

    free(head);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You free the memory, but you don't set any of the links (or the head itself) to null, so you are referencing unallocated memory.

Also: Why use recursion when a while loop would be simpler?

Comment: I would argue the recursion is simpler. Less efficient, though!

Comment: @Claudiu +1 Whether recursion means simplicity is a matter of debate, though I agree with you on this case :)

Comment: Using recursion because that is the assignment. But thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Recursion does look simple in this case, and it's fine for an assignment, but in a real world app where you list may have tens of thousands of members, you can exhaust your stack pretty quickly!

Answer (score 2):

This may be a very old question but this answer could help someone.

```
deleteList(struct node* temp)
{
     if(temp == NULL)
          printf("List is empty\n");

     else {
          head = temp;
          temp->next = NULL;
          free(temp);
          deleteList(head->next);
     }
     head = NULL;
 }
```